# GetElementsByTagName only gets the first node (XMLDocument)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument, getelementsbytagname

This is my code:

```
FileInfo[] Files = difo.GetFiles("*.xml");            
        string[] parts;
        string[] FileSearchRes = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ahodhv\Perforce\ahodhv_RD0029717_1921\prod\delivery\q_rec\int_test\SOPS", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo File in Files)

        {
            parts = File.Name.Split('_');                                             
            boxvehicles.Items.Add(parts[0]);
            string test = FileSearchRes[i];
            doc.Load(FileSearchRes[i]);
            List<string> name = new List<string>();
            var accountNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("FpcBlock");
            for (int j = 0; j < accountNodes.Count; j++)
            {
                var account = accountNodes[j].SelectSingleNode("./FPC");
                if (account != null && account.Attributes != null)
                {
                    // Read node attribute
                    name.Add(account.Attributes["Name"].Value + account.Attributes["Value"].Value);
                }
            }
                i++;            
        }
```

Im trying to read from a xml file which looks like this:

```
<FpcBlock Version="01">
        <FPC Name="1" Value="A" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="3" Value="B" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="5" Value="B" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="8" Value="B" Updated="false" />
        <FPC Name="10" Value="B" Updated="false" />
</FpcBlock>
```

The problem lies in the line:

```
var accountNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("FpcBlock");
```

accountnodes has count 1 which is incorrect since i have more nodes. Because of that only the first node is added to name. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: Sorry if i was confusing. I would like to save all the rows beneath  in a list. What i desire is that the list should be something like this:

```
1A
3B
5B
```

and so on. So i save the name and the value. But at the moment i only get the first row which is 1A.

EDIT nr 2: 
I misunderstood the `GetElementsByTagName()` method. By changing to `GetElementsByTagName("FPC")` it should the problem.

Comment: Your XML has *only one* `FpcBlock` element.  It's not clear why you think you should get more than one when there *is* only one. Is your example incomplete?

Comment: Seems like i was a bit confusing sorry. I would like everything written under <FpcBlock Version="01">. So i would like all the 5 rows beneath that

Comment: Then why not `GetElementsByTagName("FPC")`, seeing as they're the ones you actually want?

Comment: Wow, i misunderstood the GetElementsByTagName() method. Thanks that solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're querying for elements called `FpcBlock` but seem to be expecting elements called `FPC`. If you change to look for the elements you're actually trying to find, then you'll probably find the problem disappears.

That said, LINQ to XML is a much more modern, cleaner API than the old `XmlDocument` API.  It would be far nicer to work with this:

```
var nameValues = 
    from fpc in doc.Descendants("FPC")
    select new
    {
        Name = (int) fpc.Attribute("Name"),
        Value = (string) fpc.Attribute("Value")
    };
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9WEy6G) for a working demo.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this and it worked like a charm. I will mark your help as the answer.